# Removal of Bootstrap 3.0 Nav :hover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navigation, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar, nav

I kindly need some assistance to help guid me remove the Grey border that appears on "mouse hover" for all  attributes.

For an example of this: http://www.bootply.com/rUL3TbSDYS

you can see that when hovering on each attribute a grey border appears... How do I remove this?

I have traced the issue to the bootstrap class- .nav but even after removed all :hover css styles, it's still not going away.

Answer (score 0):

In your own CSS file just add a new rule to override it like:

```
.nav > li > a:hover { 
    background-color: transparent; 
}
```

[Example Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/FxTq6CpV5s)

Just be sure your CSS loads after Bootstrap's, which is good practice anyway.